# regular expression in node-express

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I'm trying to understand how can I use regular expressions in express js, I want to load a page if the url has the form '/blog_update/' and then whatever string but it just wont work
it gives back an error saying: `Cannot GET /blog_update/my_title`

```
app.get(/^\/blog_update\/[.*]/, function(req, res){

    res.render('blog_update' , {locals:{title:'Update' }});

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't character class but :

```
/^\/blog_update\/.*/
```

Comment: thanks a lot!can you please also explain how can I access second parameter with req.params ?

Comment: @rabidmachine9: Sorry, i don't know express.

Comment: Access the second parameter by using the regex `/^\/blog_update\/(.*)$/`.  The parameter will then be in `req.params[0]`.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it this way:

```
app.get('/blog_update/:id/:op?', function(req, res){
   //req.params.id
   //req.params.op
});
```

For the second parameter, here's a useful video for you:
http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/10-express-part-ii-static-files-partials-and-locals.html#video

Comment: thanks, I will check the video also... I need some node tutorials for sure :)

Answer (score 5):

```
app.get('/qwe/((\\d+))', function(req, res){
    console.log( req.params[0] );
    res.end();
});
```

this route accept only numbers